# Error while executing command line ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While executing the command line `rails -v` or `rails new project` I get the error below :

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require: cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require    from /usr/bin/rails:9:in `<main>`

My setup

```
$ruby -v 
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.12.5
$ gem -v  
2.4.5.1
```

Comment: Have you tried switching ruby version and/or reinstalling the rails gem? If you type in `gem list` what do you get?

Comment: Try Once : 
 gem install rails

Comment: hello @ Alexander I tiped the command line "gem list" ..i have just posted the output as an answer of my question

Comment: hello @Mukesh the command line "gem install rails" installed me the listed gem below:                                                                              Done installing documentation for rack, activesupport, rails-dom-testing, actionview, actionpack, method_source, railties, websocket-extensions, websocket-driver, nio4r, actioncable, activejob, actionmailer, arel, activemodel, activerecord, rails after 34 seconds
17 gems installed

Comment: Now Check rails -v

Comment: This looks like you are using a system wide Ruby (i.e. the one that comes with your Linux distro). I recommend switching to rbenv or rvm. There is a good chance this will fix your problem.

Comment: @Mukesh  rails -v
Rails 5.0.0

Comment: Now you can create your project

Comment: @Mukesh  it's works now  thanks a lot for your support